# I accidentally opened a trojan on windows XP. How to proceed?

Tags: windows-xp, trojan

I don't really need to remove it. It's ok if it just doesn't open anymore. Is there a program to remove all unwanted autoruns from registry ?

Comment: [Here]( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registry_fix ) is a good article concerning registry cleaners. While reading this, it warned to be careful using these cleaners as they can get rid of the trojans on your registry but also can delete certain data that is important to your system.

Comment: Please when you post your question, try to write details about your system and details about how trojan came into your system. So that it would be easy to rectify the problem.

Comment: --> format c:\  <--

Comment: FrozenKing I said it's a windows XP and I got the trojan by opening infected executable. This is all I guess. Formatting is not an option.

Comment: "hijack this" & "Autoruns" are 2 possible tools you could use to disable startup items, and other various things that run at boot/log-in. used in conjuction with other tools.

Comment: This question has been dealt with thoroughly in a community wiki question: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now

Comment: It kinda depends on what the "Trojan" is and how it's hooked into your system.  Most likely, since you're obviously not a computer expert, you need to use a reliable disinfectant tool.  Norton, McAfee, Kaspersky,  Microsoft, and several others make reliable tools.  Be sure to get one with firewall protection, since you obviously need it.  While you can maybe fix the current problem with a free version, expect to pay about $79 retail for a good all-in-one product to leave installed on your box.

Answer (score 5):

Free, and works well - [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/products/security-essentials/download)

Comment: Currently by far and a way my first choice for virus/malware protection on non-commercial Windows machines. Very low footprint compared it its competitiors, integrates with Windows (Firewall, Defender, Updates, etc), multiple definition updates a week (daily?) and it has the same detection rates as the 3rd party tools.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are telling it is a trojan . Use [kaspersky internet security trial version](http://www.kaspersky.com/kis-trial-register) and also use [malwarebytes trial version](http://www.malwarebytes.org/). Scan with both of them.

Answer (score 1):

hi you can use Kaspersky Poratable Edition, as you can run without installing it. it will help you, as some of the trojans will block installed antivirus program to run. so this portable version will help you to remove your trojan.

1. You can view what are all the programs are running as pc starts  by using Autoruns [Autoruns: MS SysInternals.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902)
2. Use ProcessExplorer [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to check which process is running, and kill them if you feel suspicious about it.

[Kaspersky Portable antivirus tool](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Antivirus/Kaspersky-Virus-Removal-Tool.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

Give [Windows Defender Offline](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/what-is-windows-defender-offline) a try.  You will need to create a cd/dvd or bootable thumb drive to use it.  Once you create it, boot your computer from it and scan and repair your system.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the latest Restore Point (the one before you ran that trojan) -- type in System Restore in search to see all your restore points. (Back up important files if your restore point is too far in the past.) When everything is restored, I'd download [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html), boot in a safe mode and run the whole system scan with it. You don't really need any other anti-virus programs...